# Create dropdown list of pricebooks

Tags: sobject, schema, dependent-picklist, selectoption

I'm in the process of creating a variable dependent picklist, where you can select a pricebook from a dropdown and then a multiselect picklist will show the products in that pricebook.
So far, I have started a controller to retrieve and return a list of the pricebooks, but I keep receiving an error which reads:

"Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [System.SelectOption], (Schema.SObjectField, Schema.SObjectField) at line 17 column 25"

I'm still new to this language's syntax, so I'm not entirely sure what that means.

Here is my code:

```
String[] prod = new String[]{};

public PageReference test() {
    return null;
}

//Create the dropdown menu.
public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    //Add blank option to display when the page loads.
    options.add(new SelectOption(' ', ' '));

    //Create options.        
    for (Integer i : pricebook2.name) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(pricebook2.name, pricebook2.name));
    }
    return options;
}

public String[] getProd() {
    return prod;
}

public void setProd(String[] prod) {
    this.prod = prod;
}
```

There appears to be something wrong with the loop which creates options. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here:

```
//Create options.        
for (Integer i : pricebook2.name) {
    options.add(new SelectOption(pricebook2.name, pricebook2.name));
}
```

What exactly is 'pricebook2'?

If it's a single pricebook, then you don't need a loop - just one new SelectOption.
If it's a list of pricebooks, then you need to iterate through the list:

```
List<Pricebook2> MyPricebook2List = new List<Pricebook2>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Pricebook2 ORDER BY Name ASC]);
for (Pricebook2 pb2 : MyPricebook2List) {
    options.add(new SelectOption(pb2.name, pb2.name));
}
```

Also if you're planning to work with the selected pricebook, I would put the PB2 Id as the SelectOption value as opposed to the name, like so:

```
options.add(new SelectOption(pb2.Id, pb2.name));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was trying to access the object to list the price books, but I guess the value needs to be passed through pb2?

Comment: You'll need to query for the Pricebook2 records in your org, I'll update my answer now with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I did that before using **Lightning Web Component**.

First, you need to select the list of Pricebooks from the database, to do that use an apex method that returns the list of Pricebooks(Id, Name) using a simple SOQL query as shown below:

```
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Pricebook2> getAllPricebooks() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Pricebook2];
    }
```

In your HTML page, use the lightning-combobox component to display the selected Pricebooks :

```
<lightning-combobox  name="Pricebooks"
                     label="Pricebooks"
                     placeholder="-Select Pricebook-"
                     value={value}
                     options={pricebookOptions}
                     onchange={handelPricebookChange} >
 </lightning-combobox>
```

- pricebookOptions : is a JS array that holds the list of Pricebooks, so you need to declare it in you JS file with the [@track](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/js_props_private_reactive) decorator :

  @track pricebookOptions=[];
- handelPricebookChange : The method that will be called when the user select a pricebook.

Now, you need to call your apex method, get the data and store it in your pricebookOptions property, that should be done in your **.js**, to do that :

- Import your apex method :

  import getPricebooks from '@salesforce/apex/PricebookController.getAllPricebooks';
- Run the code that allows you to get the Pricebooks automatically (after the lightning-combobox component is rendered) using the
  [connectedCallback()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_dom) method :

  ```
  connectedCallback(){

   getPricebooks().then(result => {
    for(let i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
       this.pricebookOptions = [...this.pricebookOptions,{result[i].Id 
       ,label: result[i].Name}];}              
      }).catch(error =>{// Handle errors});
  }
  ```